# New to java. Error using scanner class in while loop?

Tags: java, io

So my first assignment involves making a simple question and answer program. The user asks a question, and I generate an answer. I've never done java before. Here is my input class:

```
//msg is the msg I output (answer to their question).
//Function returns inputStr which is the question the user asks.
public String getInput(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
    Scanner theInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputStr = theInput.nextLine(); //ERROR HERE ON 2nd ITERATION!
    theInput.close();
    if (inputStr.equals("exit")) {
        System.out.println("GoodBye!"); 
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return inputStr;
}
```

The function that calls this in the while loop is as follows:

```
    //inputSource is an object that has the getInput method. It is an argument for this function.
    String userQuestion = inputSource.getInput(firstLine);
    String initMsg = processMessage(userQuestion);
    while(!initMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("GoodBye")){
        userQuestion = inputSource.getInput(initMsg);
        //Doesn't get to here.
        initMsg = processMessage(userQuestion);
    }
    System.out.println(initMsg);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
```

So basically, what happens is that it asks a question once, and then it gives back an answer once, but when it enters the while loop, it gets stuck at the indicated point.
Little help. Thank you.

Comment: Edited above, forgot, sorry. I kind of understand the error. I just don't understand why it's happening.

Comment: always make sure input is available by calling  while (sc.hasNext()) {
          then your code.
      }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that I noticed: you should probably not call `close()` on the scanner. You're closing the underlying input stream (standard input), according to the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29).

Comment: Wow, that fixed it. Can you give me more detail as to how that fixed it?

Comment: The `System.in` stream is the equivalent to `stdin` in C. It is typically not supposed to be closed. When you call `close()` on the scanner, the JavaDocs state that `if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked.` The "underlying readable" in this case is `System.in`. If you close that, you can't get any more input. =)